# Jenkins declarative pipeline docker login on osx not working

Tags: jenkins-pipeline

```
Masking supported pattern matches of $DOCKER_REGISTRY_PASSWORD or $DOCKER_REGISTRY_PASSWORD_USR or $DOCKER_REGISTRY_PASSWORD_PSW
[Pipeline] {
[Pipeline] sh
+ git rev-parse --short HEAD
[Pipeline] withEnv
Warning: A secret was passed to "withEnv" using Groovy String interpolation, which is insecure.
         Affected argument(s) used the following variable(s): [DOCKER_REGISTRY_PASSWORD_USR]
         See https://jenkins.io/redirect/groovy-string-interpolation for details.
```

This is my declarative pipeline:

```
pipeline {
    agent { label 'docker' }
    environment{
        APP = 'some-app'
        REPOSITORY = 'registry.mydomain.com'        
        DOCKER_REGISTRY_USER = 'thatsme'
        DOCKER_REGISTRY_PASSWORD = credentials('docker_registry_password')
    }
    stages {
        // ...
        stage('Deploy') {
            steps {
                //sh 'docker logout $REPOSITORY'
                //sh 'docker login $REPOSITORY -u $DOCKER_REGISTRY_USER -p $DOCKER_REGISTRY_PASSWORD'
                sh 'echo $DOCKER_REGISTRY_PASSWORD | docker login $REPOSITORY -u $DOCKER_REGISTRY_USER -p $DOCKER_REGISTRY_PASSWORD'
                sh 'docker push $REPOSITORY/$APP:latest'
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Questions:

- I don't use a variable called `DOCKER_REGISTRY_PASSWORD_USR`. I use `DOCKER_REGISTRY_PASSWORD`. Where is this coming from?
- What is `Masking supported pattern matches of ...` supposed to tell me?
- Logging in from host shell works. Only jenkins can't log in. I don't even know where to start debugging.
- I found a workaround: dont call "docker logout/login" from pipeline, but log in once on the jenkins build agent (mac osx...). I hope this survives reboots etc. There must be a real solution!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the line

```
Masking supported pattern matches of $DOCKER_REGISTRY_PASSWORD or 
   $DOCKER_REGISTRY_PASSWORD_USR or $DOCKER_REGISTRY_PASSWORD_PSW
```

I understand that your Jenkins Credentials Store has an entry by a name of `docker_registry_password` and it is of type "Username with password". Since `environment` directive sets environment variables, and environment variables cannot be anything but strings, Jenkins is "helping" you here by converting the two items in your credentials into two strings, one named `DOCKER_REGISTRY_PASSWORD_USR` (holding the username part) and the other, `DOCKER_REGISTRY_PASSWORD_PSW` (holding the password part).

With that, I don't have any idea what goes into a string named `DOCKER_REGISTRY_PASSWORD`, as a complex object ("username with password") cannot simply go into a string.

The rest of your issue is just a consequence of the above.

You can solve your problem by one of the below:

- Instead of "username with password", you can have a Credential of the type "Secret text". Put your password there, as I see you don't mind having the username in cleartext.
- Instead of loading credentials in the `environment` block, load them once needed:

```
withCredentials([usernamePassword(
  credentialsId: 'docker_registry_password', // bad name: it's not a password but username+password
  passwordVariable: 'MY_DOCKER_PASSWORD',
  usernameVariable: 'MY_DOCKER_USER')]) {
        sh 'docker login $REPOSITORY -u $MY_DOCKER_USER -p $MY_DOCKER_PASSWORD'
        sh 'docker push $REPOSITORY/$APP:latest'
}
```

Comment: Using the `withCredentials()` is way better than fiddling with the `_USR` and `_PSW` variables.

Comment: @Yuri what about if the same credentials are used 3 times in the jenkins file?

Comment: @Solubris I'd declare the credentials in each step (1-3) using them. It is declarative enough for me.